Find $UAV = \begin{bmatrix} I_r &0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix} $ such that $U,V$ are invertible, where $r$ is A's rank.

Find $UAV = \begin{bmatrix} I_r &0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix} $ such that
$U,V$  are invertible, where $A's$ rank is $r$

Here, $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&-1\\ -2&-2&4 \end{bmatrix}$ ( which is of rank 2)
Now it's obvious that  matrix $U$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix , and $V$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix.
So I first Found that matrix that row-reduced matrix $A$ to its RREF form.
which is
$$U=\begin{bmatrix} 2& 1/2 \\ 1&1/2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Beyond this I'm rather lost. I thought the identity matrix would work, but that doesn't give me a matrix of the form
$\begin{bmatrix} I_r &0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix} $.
I then  considered  taking the transpose of both sides to get
$V^{T} \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} $.
Not too sure of what I should make of this .
Could I have a hint please

You're almost there!
First note that, because the matrixes $U$ and $V$ are square, the matrix $UAV$ will have the same shape as $A$. That means you're going to end up with will look like $\begin{bmatrix} I_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
If we set $A_1 = UA = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$, by taking the transpose you're looking for $V$ such that $V^TA_1^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$. This is the same as reducing $A_1^T$ to its RREF, which you can do in the same way as your first step.
More abstractly, multiplying by $V$ on the right is the same as doing column operations, rather than row operations. By taking the transpose, you turn the columns into rows & you can proceed as before.

ooh, got it. Thanks a lot!
